# How to transfor soap fault message in xslt transformation

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, transform, wso2-esb

how to create xslt which transforms the response message to a soap fault message.please refer the Attached the Input and what i expected  Output,xslt Result after xslt transformation.

This is my xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <soapenv:Fault>
            <soapenv:Code>
                <soapenv:Value>soapenv:Sender</soapenv:Value>
            </soapenv:Code>
            <soapenv:Reason>
                <soapenv:Text xml:lang="en">User NotFound</soapenv:Text>
            </soapenv:Reason>
            <soapenv:Detail>
                <axis2ns4:sdpFault xmlns:axis2ns4="http://testservice.com/uat/testservice"> 
                    <axis2ns4:resultNameCode>2</axis2ns4:resultNameCode>
                    <axis2ns4:resultNameType>GH</axis2ns4:resultNameType>
                </axis2ns4:sdpFault>
            </soapenv:Detail>
        </soapenv:Fault>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Expecte result

set this message `<soapenv:Text xml:lang="en">User NotFound</soapenv:Text>`

```
<ns1:UserDescription>User NotFound</ns1:UserDescription>
```

Comment: *I need* is not a question.

Comment: @michael.hor257k sorry mistake.any idea about this?

Comment: Why do you not use a PayloadFactory ?

Comment: @Robyn.D normally i use xslt transformation to transform.